# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException Java

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I'm trying to call 2 different versions of the same dependency library (`jars`) within a top level `Main class`. So I created an interface with 2 implementation classes, both classes have a run method which makes use of common apis one will use `somejar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and the other will use `somejar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` by explicitly calling ClassLoader.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    ClassLoader loader1 = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { new File("/Users/haddad/.m2/repository/com/company/somejar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar").toURL() });
    ClassLoader loader2 = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { new File("/Users/haddad/.m2/repository/com/company/somejar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar").toURL() });

    Class<?> c1 = loader1.loadClass("com.engine.na.EngineV1");
    Class<?> c2 = loader2.loadClass("com.engine.na.EngineV2");

    IEngine app1 = (IEngine) c1.newInstance();
    IEngine app2 = (IEngine) c2.newInstance();

    Integer s1 = app1.run();
    Integer s2 = app2.run();
    Assert.equals(s1,s2,"Outputs from somejar-1.0 and somejar-2.0 did not match, perhaps somejar-2.0 has regressed?");
}
```

Here are EngineV1 and V2 with Interface:

```
public Interface IEngine {
    Integer run();
}

public class EngineV1 implements IEngine {
    private File content;
    private File en;
    public EngineV1(args) {
       this.content = new File("/some/path");
       this.en = new File("/some/path");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EngineV1(args).run();
    }

    public Integer run() {
        // some logic...
        somejar.evaluateSpeed();
    }
}

public class EngineV2 implements IEngine {
    private File content;
    private File en;
    public EngineV2(args) {
       this.content = new File("/some/path");
       this.en = new File("/some/path");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EngineV2(args).run();
    }

    public Integer run() {
        // some logic...
        somejar.evaluateSpeed();
    }
}
```

When I go to run the main class I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: com.engine.na.EngineV1
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at com.engine.na.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.engine.na.EngineV1.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 1 more
```

Why do I get this error? How to solve for this?

Comment: Give your classes a default constructor.

Comment: Does not java implicitly create a no arguments constructor for EngineV1 and EngineV2?

Comment: Yes Java generate it for you at compile time but I think that you declare a no arg constructor in EngineV1.

Comment: Give it a noargs constructor.

Comment: That worked!!!! But I don't understand why?

Comment: Because when you give your class a constructor, you don't get a default constructor - that only happens for classes with no declared constructors. The error message was pretty clear - it was trying to call init with no args and there was no such thing.

Comment: You probably don't need the explicit use of the classloader, if your use case looks similar to what you've written.

Comment: @pvg Why would use of classloader not be needed? I need the classloader to load different versions of the same library somejar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and somejar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar for c1 and c2 respectively. How else could I accomplish this?

Comment: Your classes already have different names in your example. There isn't much difference between hardcoding their names in as strings and simply referring to them. They get loaded dynamically anyway, from the classpath.

Comment: @pvg I think you misundersand what I'm trying to accomplsih. Both EngineV1 and EngineV2 class's run methods makes calls to a library called `somejar` but I want them to call it to different versions 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT respectively. So EngineV1 will make use of 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and EngineV2 will make use of 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT of somejar.jar. So for this to happen would I need to use classloader or is there some other way? I am starting to question whether or not my solution works properly

Comment: Possibly, but you haven't explained what you're actually trying to do very clearly. It still sounds like simply setting the classpath ought to do it. Again, not completely sure what you're trying to do but it feels like you've reached for the industrial laser cutter when you probably just wanted a pen-knife.

Comment: @pvg Apologies for the lack of clarity. What I'm trying to do is, use 2 versions of the same library in one class. I'm creating a commandline utility which would ensure parity between `somejar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `somejar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Basically calling methods from `somejar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `somejar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and ensure the output is the same. Doing it this way just made sense to me, but I feel you have a better grasp on this than I do. I hope this makes sense enough for you to tell me if this is a correct approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a constructor in a class, the default constructor with no argument is not generated at compile time.

You have two ways :

- adding explicitly a constructor with no argument.
- invoking by reflection the constructor with an argument.

The first way is the easy trick and is a very generic way but it not necessarily the best way if it matters to value the state or one of part of the instance when it is created.

For this first case, it is self explanatory.
For the second case, the idea is you have to retrieve the constructor with argument from the class and specify the argument when you use it.

For example with this constructor :

```
public EngineV1(String value) {
      ...
}
```

You can invoke it in this way :

```
Class<EngineV1> c1 = (Class<EngineV1>)loader1.loadClass("com.engine.na.EngineV1");
Constructor<EngineV1> constructor = c1.getConstructor(String.class);
EngineV1 instance = ctor.newInstance("myString");
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no constructor defined in class then only compiler will create a **no-arg** constructor for your class.

But as in your case you are defining a parameterized constructor and in that case you need to provide a **no-arg** constructor for Reflection to create instances by calling it.

Or you can check available constructors for your class by calling **getConstructor()** method and then call **newInstance()** on that.

Follow below link for more information :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html